# Full screen app with NSToolbar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, fullscreen, nswindow

This is hard for me to explain, so please bear with me for a minute.

In Xcode, if it is in full screen mode, showing the app's menu also moves the toolbar down. I have tried to make an NSView move and resize whenever the menu bar is shown, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I think this has something to do with and event, because setting struts and springs in Xcode does not make it move automatically. Can anybody help me figure out what the event is?

Edit: I just re-thought my question, and I have to make a correction. NSToolbar does this on it's own. I want a normal NSView to move and resize itself when the window goes into full screen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be having the same issue as I was - if so, you need to call `[NSToolbar setFullScreenAccessoryView:]` on the "accessory view" you want to glue to the bottom of the NSToolbar.

Note that in windowed mode, your accessory view should take up space in the NSWindow's contentView just like any other view, but when you enter fullscreen mode you'll want to remove the accessory view somehow since Cocoa rips it out of your layout and leaves a gap unless you account for that.

I can certainly understand this issue being difficult to explain without having the background knowledge - I had the same problem. :)

Also see: [How can I get a two-row toolbar like in Mail.app and Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712287/how-can-i-get-a-two-row-toolbar-like-in-mail-app-and-xcode)