# How can I get a two-row toolbar like in Mail.app and Xcode?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nstoolbar

I'm trying to add a "second row" after my NSToolbar in my app, that remains part of the title bar. As an example, Mail has a thin gray divider line below the NSToolbar with some extras items below that. Very specifically, when the window is put into fullscreen mode, that second "row" stays attached to the title bar as it slides down under the system menu bar. Xcode has a similar story.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried setting my NSWindow to textured and placing my second row controls directly in the content view of the window. While this mostly looks correct in windowed mode, those controls of course won't appear attached to the toolbar when it slides down in fullscreen mode. So how can I achieve the same behavior that Mail and Xcode do? I've looked at a lot of toolbar customization code but none of them really cover this specific case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I needed to do was call `[NSToolbar setFullScreenAccessoryView:]` on the view below my toolbar. This results in the behavior I was aiming for. See the [NSToolbar documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this method.

Answer (score 6):

`fullScreenAccessoryView` is deprecated in macOS 10.10

In order to do this in recent versions of macOS, use the `addTitlebarAccessoryViewController` method on your `NSWindow` and pass in a subclass of `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController`.

For example:

```
NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController *accessoryViewController = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccessoryViewController"];
[self.mainWindowController.window addTitlebarAccessoryViewController:accessoryViewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

First one is normal toolbar. For second toolbar you can create a separate view of your desired height and add it in the main landing-window.

Comment: "add it in the main landing window"? See, specifically the problem is that this separate view is not "attached" to the toolbar as shown in the fullscreen screenshot...

Comment: Once you add a subview to the mainView, it will give the feel that you have one window and each and every component is ONE. You cant move or drag any of the subview. It will look like an attached to the main toolbar. I can not show the screen shot either, because there is some client restriction ;)   And I assure you the client is  none other than .... :)

Comment: In the last two screen captures, you can see that the actual NSToolbar covers the secondary toolbar in fullscreen mode. How can I make the "secondary" toolbar also slide down with the toolbar itself?

Comment: You can check whether your app is in fullscreen mode or not, if it is in fullscreen mode hide/remove your secondary(faking toolbar). And if you wish to adjust the size of the primary toolbar you can do.